# Conjecture: all complex roots of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{\left(nk\right)!}$ are real

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, conjectures, mittag-leffler-function

Conjecture:
$$\left[n\in\mathbb{Z}^+,z\in\mathbb{C},0=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{\left(nk\right)!}\right]\Rightarrow z\in\mathbb{R}$$
This conjecture has been verified for $n\in\{1,2,4\}$.

The motivation for this conjecture arose during [the study of the exponential sum function](https://www.dropbox.com/s/07f5z3y26qw55w8/RootOfUnityExponentialSumFunction.pdf?dl=0) which has applications to exponentiation in rings with abelian multiplication: $$\text{rues}_n\left(z\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{nk}}{\left(nk\right)!}=\frac{1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^n \exp\left(ze^{2ki\pi/n}\right)$$

Comment: $e^z$ does not have any roots and thus $n=1$ is vacuously true. $0\neq e^{2ki\pi}=1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has been shown that the zeros of the [Mittag-Leffler function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.46.E3)
$$E_{\alpha}(z)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{\Gamma(\alpha n+1)}\quad(\alpha > 0)$$
are real and negative whenever $\alpha\geq 2$.

See Wiman (1905) and Pólya (1921).

Wiman, A. 1905. “[Über die Nullstellen der Funktionen $E_a(x)$](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02403204).” *Acta Mathematica* **29**: 217–34.

Pólya, G. 1921. “[Bemerkung Über Die Mittag-Lefflerschen Funktionen $E_a(z)$](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/tmj1911/19/0/19_0_241/_article/-char/ja/).” *Tohoku Mathematical Journal*, First Series **19**: 241–48.

Comment: Is a proof available in English?